# Prevent insert/update on a default value column

Tags: sql-server

We are adding a sequence as a default value on a column. We want to prevent most users but not all users from inserting their own value or updating the value of the column. For the most part, we want an identity column. We cannot add an identity column because of locking issues while the identity column is added. The table has 9 billion rows.

I've tried to add an AFTER trigger to prevent inserts and updates to the column, but I haven't found a way to find out if the value from the inserted column is the sequence value. Additionally, the table doesn't have a primary key or a good way to identify the row.

Does anyone have any ideas for enforcing the default value to be the next value from the sequence for most but not all users?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.BankId','SO') IS NOT NULL
       DROP SEQUENCE dbo.BankId;


CREATE SEQUENCE BankId
AS BIGINT
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
NO MAXVALUE
NO CYCLE
CACHE 10000;


alter table BankImport
add BankId bigint default next value for BankId;
alter table Bank
add BankId bigint default next value for BankId;
alter table BankImportHold
add BankId bigint default next value for BankId;
alter table Bankarchive
add BankId bigint default next value for BankId;


IF OBJECT_ID ('BankEnforceID','TR') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TRIGGER BankEnforceID;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.BankEnforceID ON bank
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM inserted AS i
           where i.BankID is not NULL
          )
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Cannot specify a value for BankID', 16, 1);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN 
END;
GO
```

Comment: Honestly I am trying to get my head around this.  You want some people to use a sequence and other people can just add an ID however they want? won't you have a problem when the person who gets to add an ID doesn't know about the sequence and reuses an existing ID?  And since you have no way of identifying any individual row how would you ever fix it?

Comment: @JMabee The people who would be able to add it wouldn't be people--it would be an import program.

Comment: Still would be the same problem.  But I would also suggest you just create a new table with an IDENTITY column and move the rows over. Andy Mallon has a great write up of just how to do this: https://am2.co/2019/12/changing-a-column-from-int-to-bigint-without-downtime/

Comment: @JMabee I didn't design the plan to use sequences. I am just trying to implement it. I am afraid if I go back and suggest identity that it wouldn't go over well. However, I think your suggestion is very good.

Comment: I honestly and sincerely wish you the best of luck with this. I would only add that having that conversation now might be tough, but if you are the person that has to maintain this in the future I would look ahead to what that talk will sound like. Just from what you have provided this sounds like it is going to be pain.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just define a new table with the appropriate structure and with an IDENTITY column and then `SET IDENTITY INSERT ON` for this new table so that the existing values can be copied across and then `INSERT INTO new table SELECT * FROM old table`.

You then would reseed the IDENTITY so that it continued from the largest value that was there previously.